# I want to calculate weekly returns from daily prices

Tags: r

I am new to R and I would like to calculate weekly returns using wednesday-to-wednesday cloing prices as I am working with stock market indices from different countries.

To do so, I download from quantmod the daily closing prices:

```
getSymbols("^GDAXI",from="2001-12-19", to = "2022-03-18")
GDAXI2<-GDAXI[,4]
```

And i get an "xts" "zoo":

```
               GDAXI.Close
2001-12-19     4984.69
2001-12-20     4934.14
2001-12-21     5019.01
2001-12-24     NA
2001-12-25     NA
2001-12-26     NA
2001-12-27     5117.13
2001-12-28     5160.10 
2001-12-31     NA
2002-01-01     NA
2002-01-02     5167.88
2002-01-03     5270.29
```

I then use the following code to obtain only the Wednesday closing prices:

```
wednesday = as.POSIXlt(time(GDAXI2))$wday == 3
indx <- c(0, which(wednesday))
GDAXI3<-period.apply(GDAXI2, INDEX=indx, FUN=last)
```

I obtain the following data ("xts" "zoo"):

```
               GDAXI.Close
2001-12-19     4984.69 
2001-12-26     NA 
2002-01-02     5167.88
2002-01-09     5288.21
2002-01-16     4984.20
2002-01-23     5163.03
```

The problem is that there may be a Wednesday that is a holiday., so I get a missing value.

"In the cases in which Wednesdays were not active trading days, the closing values from the next date with valid prices from the sequence of the nearest days is used: Tuesday, Thursday, Monday, and Friday.  More days are usually unnecessary"

I need help, If one week does not include a Wednesday, I want to exctract the following weekday.
I would like to replace (f.e.) the missing value of that Wednesday with the data of the following day (2001-12-27)

I also found this interesting topic:

[Calculate weekly returns from daily prices In R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378664/calculate-weekly-returns-from-daily-prices-in-r)

but I can't run the script made by Joshua Ulrich, I obtain the following error with my data:

```
Error in try.xts(NA) : 
  Error in as.xts.logical(x, ..., .RECLASS = TRUE) :   order.by must be either 'names()' or otherwise specified
```

Script made by Joshua Ulrich:

```
    WedOrNext <- function(w) {
  # find all the weekdays after Tuesday and before Saturday
  iwd <- .indexwday(w)
  i <- iwd > 2 & iwd < 6

  # determine which row to return
  if (any(i)) {
    # return the first weekday after Tuesday
    w[i][1L]
  } else {
    # return NA if there are no weekdays after Tuesday
    NA
  }
}
```

Attempt with my original data (daily closing prices):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(GDAXI2, "weeks"), WedOrNext))
```

Output:

```
Error in try.xts(NA) : Error in as.xts.logical(x, ..., .RECLASS = TRUE) :   order.by must be either 'names()' or otherwise specified
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can get these weekly prices or can you tell me why I can't run Joshua's script?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If we convert to ts and back again to xts then that will fill in all missing dates with NA and then we can use `na.locf0(x)` and `na.locf0(x, fromLast = TRUE)` to fill them in from the forward and backward directions.  (Note that `Cl` picks out the close column -- you may also wish to consider using `Ad` for the adjusted close.)

```
x <- as.xts(as.ts(Cl(GDAXI)))
```